# three.js showing 3d objects in same perspective

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new to three.js, 
what I am trying to achieve is ti have multiple cubes with same perspective

```
var g = new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200, 1, 1, 1);                
cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(g, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
cube1.position.set(0,0,0);
cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(g, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
cube2.position.set(300,0,0);
```

This will give me x align cubes but cube2 is rotated slightly! 
Advice on what to look for would be really helpful, Thanks!

Comment: What you mean by "same perpective"? What you actually describe are two cubes seen "in perspective" - they appear slightly different because they have different distance from camera. Two cubes in perspective view will only look same if they are in the same position and same size - basically "same cube" :-) I wonder what you are really trying to achieve here. Take a look on what is orthographic camera - maybe that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! If reason for them to appear slight different is their distance from camera, my goal is to look exactly the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use orthographic camera instead of perspective camera. Your camera initializiation will look something like this:

```
var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( width / - 2, width / 2, height / 2, height / - 2, near, far );
```

where width and length are dimensions of canvas. Near and far define maximum and minimum distance from the camera (objects not within this range will not be rendered)

with orthographic camera boxes of same size and rotation will appear exactly same no matter of their position.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that creates cubes and then call it in a loop. Not tested but something like this should give you the desired result:

```
// Function to create cubes
function create_cube(x,y,z,rx,ry,rz,color) {
    var geometry, material;
    geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(5,5,5);
    material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: color});
    cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    cube.position.x += x;
    cube.position.y += y;
    cube.position.z += z;
    cube.rotation.x += rx;
    cube.rotation.y += ry;
    cube.rotation.z += rz;
    cube.castShadow = true;
    return cube;
}

// Create 10 cubes
var n=10;
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cube = create_cube(10*i,10*i,10*i,i,i,i,0xffffff);
    scene.add(cube)
}
```

You can use the value of i to control how each successive cube differs from the last.